# could not open acquire_lock

Tags: endeca

In endeca I just tried to load the templates using the below commands in Linux terminal

```
emgr_update --host localhost:172.20.187.149 --action set_templates --prefix MyApp --dir /home/Admin/endeca/apps/MyApp/config/cartridge_templates -app_name MyApp
```

got an error:
`could not open acquire_lock.status`
I tried that while running http tool service and workbench service and stopped both services. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue and it was a typo in the name of the host that when fixed resolved this error.

For your emgr_update command above, I couldn't help but notice that the format of the --host parameter is incorrect.  You have --host localhost:172.20.187.149 and it should be in the format of <host>:<port>.  So I'm thinking that you meant either localhost:8006 or 172.20.187.149:8006 (where 8006 is the port that Workbench is configured to listen on).

Answer (score 0):

Check the flags on your app.  If an update or baseline exited improperly, the locking flags may still be in-place.

```
eaccmd list-flags --app MyApp
```

That should list any flags that might be preventing your update.  Depending on the output of that command, you can remove any flags with this command:

```
eaccmd remove-flag --app MyApp --flag <flagNameGoesHere>
```

Answer (score 0):

PlatformService and ToolsAndFramework (previously Workbench) must be running when setting or getting templates. -app_name should also be --app_name (not sure if that was a typo).